# Effective and relative address in 8086

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

im not sure in 8086 that i understand it right but i want to share it 
CS,Ds,ss,es are stores the pointer to segment in the memory 
cs:ip => say the relative address of current instruction 
and if we want to calculate the physical address(or effective) address we just adding a 0h to end of the code segment and add it with ip
ds:bx say the relative address of data 
and if we want to calculate the physical address(or effective) address we just adding a 0h to end of the Data segment and add it with bx

am i understanding right??!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in other words, multiply the segment by 16/shift it left by four, and add the offset to it.